# Protractor: Running multiple browsers

Tags: selenium, protractor

How to exclude one specific browser from the browser: 'ALL' argument in the protractor config file.

Eg: browser: 'ALL -iexplore' //Excludes iexplore from the desired browsers

Any ideas? 
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to list the browsers you want individually. Other than not having that browser available on your test platform (Safari on PC, for example) I can't see any reason to exclude a browser unless you have a very targeted audience.

Comment: The thing here is: the target is a node not containing IE10 browser, but I want all others to load (except IE10)
As you say then I must set one by one?